# Maven RPM Plugin does not generate the scriptlets specified

Tags: maven-plugin, rpm, rpm-spec, rpm-maven-plugin

I am trying to create an rpm package with the help of the rpm-maven-plugin.

All goes well until I try to have it generate the %pre scriptlet (or any scriptlet for that matter)

The pom.xml excerpt is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>attached-rpm</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <copyright>Copyright 2010 XXX, Inc. All rights reserved</copyright>
        <vendor>XXX, Inc.</vendor>
        <group>Applications/System</group>
        <packager>${env.USER}</packager>
        <needarch>true</needarch>
        <prefix>/usr/xxx</prefix>
        <mappings></mappings>

        <preinstallScriptlet>
            <script>echo "installing now"</script>
        </preinstallScriptlet>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

... And the generated Spec file is:

```
Name: Server
Version: 1.0.0.0
Release: 01_1
Summary: Server Maven Webapp
License: Copyright 2010 XXX, Inc. All rights reserved
Vendor: XXX, Inc.
Group: Applications/System
Packager: yaneeve
Prefix: /usr/xxx
BuildRoot: ....../target/rpm/buildroot

%description
Server

%files
```

Note: the mappings tag does produce the relevant mappings but has been removed here for clarity purposes. Either way - the sciptlets do not get generated.

Any input?

Thanks all

**EDIT 1:**

Built with both Maven 2 and 3 - result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if its a matter of plugin version...

Instead of 2.0-beta-2 the required version to support scriptlets is **2.1-alpha-1**