# Why is the RPM postinstallScriptlet in pom file not executed

Tags: maven-3, rpm-maven-plugin

[Maven RPM Plugin does not generate the scriptlets specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062201/maven-rpm-plugin-does-not-generate-the-scriptlets-specified)

I'm using maven 3.0.5. I thought the above post answered my question but I am using the rpm-maven-plugin version described in the post.

I have in my pom file a scriptlet that supposed to create a soft link,

```
<postinstallScriptlet>
    <script>cd /usr/lib64; ln -s libodbccr.so.1.0.0 libodbccr.so</script>
</postinstallScriptlet>
```

But I don't see the soft link. Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't tell the whole story, I actually had this

```
<postinstallScriptlet>
    <script>cd /usr/lib64; ln -s libodbccr.so.1.0.0 libodbccr.so</script>
    <script>echo "Finished Script"</script>
</postinstallScriptlet>
```

With postinstallScriptlet only the LAST script is executed, so I had to change it, like this

```
<postinstallScriptlet>
    <script>
        cd /usr/lib64; \
        ln -s libodbccr.so.1.0.0 libodbccr.so<; \
        echo "Finished Script"
    </script>
</postinstallScriptlet>
```

Comment: You should move the first part of your answer to the question (as an edit). Then this would match the Q&A style and I would +1 both.